# Is it possible to construct a while loop with an indeterminate number of repetitions in Maxima

Tags: loops, matrix, while-loop, maxima

I have an inequality `A.x >= b`, where `A` is a row vector (a Maxima matrix), `x` a column vector whose each element is nonnegative  and `b` some positive constant. If the coefficients in the matrix `A` are too small the inequality will not hold and Maxima throws an error.

I would like to make a `while` loop that calculates a new `A.x` until `A.x >= b`, if necessary. How could I achieve this in Maxima. There seems to only be a `for` construct mentioned in the docs, but I don't know how many iterations it would take in case there was an error so using that does not make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for` and `while` loops can be structured in various ways. Much of the documentation is under `do`, which, I guess, is confusing. Anyway `? do` at the input prompt will show some info.

In this case I think `while A.x < b do (A: somefunction())` might have the effect you want.